# What happens when I deploy a workflow with Camunda?

Tags: process, workflow, bpmn, camunda, camunda-modeler

I use Camunda 4.8 Modeler. When I deploy a workflow with the Camunda Modeler by setting the URL, the process (modelization) is translated/converted to a data in database or the BPMN file is stored somewhere in the server or there is another way to save the workflow and read it after that with a web service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modeler connects to the REST API (https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/reference/rest/deployment/) to send the process model (and DMN or forms) to the server, which stores it as a new version in the database. Newly started process instances will now be started on this model version. Already running instance will continue running on the version they are started on, unless you migrate them to a different version.

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.17/introduction/architecture/

> BPMN 2.0 Core Engine: This is the core of the process engine. It
> features a lightweight execution engine for graph structures (PVM -
> Process Virtual Machine), a BPMN 2.0 parser which transforms BPMN 2.0
> XML files into Java Objects and a set of BPMN Behavior implementations
> (providing the implementation for BPMN 2.0 constructs such as Gateways
> or Service Tasks).